# Adding a subview to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I do not understand why my scrollview is not being loaded on the coordinates I tell it to load at. I load the subview using the following code:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.bounds.width * CGFloat(i), 0, scrollView.bounds.width, scrollView.bounds.height)

scrollView.addSubview(view)
```

However it's not completely touching the top of the scrollview as I would expect it to:

[image: This is what the screen looks like when loaded for the first time]

But when I start interacting with my subview it shoots up to the position where I wanted it to be:

[image: This is what the screen looks like when there has been interaction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets** property of your view controller to false in **viewDidLoad**.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

The default value of this property is "true", which allows the view controller to adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar.